# How do i convert row.names to a column using R

Tags: sql, r, csv, vsql

This is what I get when I

```
P<- unique(sqlQuery(ch, "Select * FROM TABLE"))

    rownames Maths Science English Art Chinese
1    Hazel    1      1        1     0     1
2    Haley    0      1        0     1     1
3    Shawn    1      1        1     1     1 
4    Kaze     0      0        0     0     0
```

To convert it likes this converting the row.names to the 1st column.

```
        Maths Science English Art Chinese
Hazel    1      1        1     0     1
Haley    0      1        0     1     1
Shawn    1      1        1     1     1 
Kaze     0      0        0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

Assign entries from the column "rownames" to the rownames of the data frame P.

```
rownames(P) <- P$rownames
```

Delete rownames column of data frame P.

```
P<-P[,-1]
```

Comment: it doenst delete inside the data frame :(

Comment: nvm I got it thnks !! :) P<-P[,-1]